# I have two radio buttons where single selection is to be performed.But and on single row both radio buttons are getting selected

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

[i have added an image of these issue after a solution provided where previous does not unselect  and on scroll checked values disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYvPE.jpg)I am trying to select one captain and one vice-captain from 11 players using two radio buttons which are in recycler view adapter. Data is in ArrayList. Where a single selection is working but I am using modal class to store value captain and vice-captain like true for the captain and true for vice-captain but it's not storing value. Before selecting any captain and vice-captain there values are false only for both.
if I select a player Name A as captain and later I want to change him to vice-captain then the vice-captain button is selected also captain radio button is not unselecting. 
I have got stuck in this problem not getting a solution . Can anyone help, please.

```
public class Custom_Team_adpt extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom_Team_adpt.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    public static ArrayList<PlayerTeams> playerTeamsArrayList;
    RadioButton selected=null;
    RadioButton selected1=null;
    public static RadioButton lastChecked = null;
    public static int lastCheckedPos = 0;
    public static int clickedPos;

    public static RadioButton lastChecked1 = null;
    public static int lastCheckedPos1 = 0;
    int clickedPos1;

    public RadioButton cb1;
    public RadioButton cb;






    public Custom_Team_adpt(Context context, ArrayList<PlayerTeams> playerTeamsArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.playerTeamsArrayList = playerTeamsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_team_list,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        Picasso.with(context).load(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getPlayer_pic()).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.player_name_txt.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getPlayer_name());
        holder.player_points.setText(""+playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getPlayer_points());

        if (playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getTeam_id().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

            holder.team_name.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.team_one_bg));
            holder.team_name.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getPlayer_team());
        }
        else {
            holder.team_name.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getPlayer_team());
            holder.team_name.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.team_two_bg));
        }

        holder.captain_pts.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getIs_captain_per());

        holder.vc_pts.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getIs_vice_captain_per());

        holder.type.setText(playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).getType());
        holder.captain.setTag(new Integer(position));
        holder.vice_captain.setTag(new Integer(position));

**captain button selection**


        holder.captain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cb = (RadioButton) v;
                clickedPos = ((Integer)cb.getTag()).intValue();
                if(cb.isChecked())
                {
                    if(lastChecked != null)
                    {
                        lastChecked.setChecked(false);
                        playerTeamsArrayList.get(lastCheckedPos).setIs_captain(false);
                        //  Toast.makeText(context, "Uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    lastChecked = cb;
                    lastCheckedPos = clickedPos;


                }
                else
                {

                    lastChecked=null;
                    playerTeamsArrayList.get(clickedPos).setIs_captain(true);
                }



            }
        });

    **vice captain button selection**
        holder.vice_captain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cb1 = (RadioButton) v;
                clickedPos1 = ((Integer)cb1.getTag()).intValue();
                if(cb1.isChecked())
                {
                    if(lastChecked1 != null)
                    {
                        lastChecked1.setChecked(false);
                        playerTeamsArrayList.get(lastCheckedPos1).setIs_vice_captain(false);


                    }
                    lastChecked1 = cb1;
                    lastCheckedPos1 = clickedPos1;

                }
                else
                {
                    lastChecked1 = null;
                    playerTeamsArrayList.get(clickedPos1).setIs_vice_captain(true);

                }

            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return playerTeamsArrayList.size();
    }




    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout selection;
        ImageView  imageView;
        TextView     player_name_txt;
        final TextView   player_points;

        public  RadioButton  captain;
        public  RadioButton  vice_captain;
        TextView   captain_pts;
        TextView   vc_pts;
        TextView  team_name;
        TextView  type;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            setIsRecyclable(false);
            selection=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_lay);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            player_name_txt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
            player_points=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_points);
            captain=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.captain_click);
            vice_captain=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vice_captain_click);
            captain_pts=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.captain_percent);
            vc_pts=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vice_cp_percent);
            team_name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_name);

            type=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_txt);



        }
    }


}
```

**custom_team_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/select_lay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2sp"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="0.1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_pic"

                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="CSK"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/opensanslight"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:background="#44BDF1"
                        android:id="@+id/team_name"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/type_bg"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="WK"
                        android:id="@+id/type_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/opensanslight"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="0.5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="M Dhoni"
                    android:id="@+id/player_name"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="3sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="250 "
                    android:id="@+id/player_points"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="3sp"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="0.1">


                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:src="@drawable/captain"
                    android:id="@+id/captain_click"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#2196F3"
                    android:tag="captain"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:text="50%"
                    android:id="@+id/captain_percent"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#2F2F30"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    />




            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="0.1">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/vice_captain_click"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:tag="vice_captain"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.05"
                    android:text="40%"
                    android:id="@+id/vice_cp_percent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensansregular"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#2F2F30"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>





        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Place inside a **RadioGroup** and set listener to **RadioGroup**. Can you share your `R.layout.custom_team_list`?

Comment: Yes will share it. But i had tried with radio group but values wont get stored in modal class

Comment: Check solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901358/2637449)

Comment: its for a single row but if i select player B as captain and in if i select player E as captain then player B should get un selected  same as for vice captain.. its not working @Md.Asaduzzzaman

Comment: That's mean you want to perform this operation not on a ROW item instead of whole items. Am I right?

Comment: yes on whole items like user cannot select both in same row but one will be captain and another will be vice captain. @Md.Asaduzzaman

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioGroup in this case: 
setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener): Register a callback to be invoked when the checked radio button changes in this group.

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
ArrayList<String> players;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
    players = stringList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    return new MainViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if ("Captain" == players.get(position)) {
        holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_c);
    } else {
        holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_vc);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.size();
}

class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    View mView;

    public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        radioGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rg);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        if (i == R.id.rb_vc) {
            players.set(getAdapterPosition(), "ViceCaptain");
        } else if (i == R.id.rb_c) {
            players.set(getAdapterPosition(), "Captain");
        }
    }
}
```

}

XML

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vice Captain"
            android:id="@+id/rb_vc"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Captain"
            android:id="@+id/rb_c"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**I made changes using your code. I am using modal class where actual value of captain and vice captain is false so in bindviewholder I changed condition with boolean one.But here it works only for row not for all[previous selection is not getting unselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAsha.jpg)
These are changes made now.**

```
public class Custom_Team_adpt extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom_Team_adpt.MainViewHolder> {

    Context context;
   public static ArrayList<PlayerTeams> playerTeamsArrayList;

 public Custom_Team_adpt(Context context, ArrayList<PlayerTeams> playerTeamsArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.playerTeamsArrayList = playerTeamsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_team_list,parent,false);
        MainViewHolder viewHolder=new MainViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (true == playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).isIs_captain()) {
            holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_c);
        }
        else if (true == playerTeamsArrayList.get(position).isIs_vice_captain()){
            holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_vc);
        }
 }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return playerTeamsArrayList.size();
    }
class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        View mView;

        public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            radioGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if (i == R.id.rb_vc) {
                playerTeamsArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setIs_vice_captain(true);
            } else if (i == R.id.rb_c) {
                playerTeamsArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setIs_vice_captain(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please check this updated code and let me know if it is working:

```
public class MainAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> players;
MainViewModel mViewModel;

String captain = "Captain";
String viceCaptain = "ViceCaptain";


public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> stringList, MainViewModel viewModel) {
    players = stringList;
    mViewModel = viewModel;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    return new MainViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    if (captain.equals(players.get(position))) {
        holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_c);
    } else if (viceCaptain.equals(players.get(position))) {
        holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.rb_vc);
    } else {
        holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }
    holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(holder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.size();
}

class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;

    public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        radioGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rg);
        rb1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb_c);
        rb2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rb_vc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        if (i == R.id.rb_vc) {
            int position = players.indexOf(viceCaptain);
            Collections.replaceAll(players, viceCaptain, "");
            players.set(getAdapterPosition(), viceCaptain);
            mViewModel.updateLiveData(position);
        } else if (i == R.id.rb_c) {
            int position = players.indexOf(captain);
            Collections.replaceAll(players, captain, "");
            players.set(getAdapterPosition(), captain);
            mViewModel.updateLiveData(position);
        } else {
            players.set(getAdapterPosition(), "");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MainViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("Captain");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("ViceCaptain");
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    final MainAdapter mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(strings, viewModel);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

    viewModel.update.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(final Integer integer) {
            if (integer != -1) {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mainAdapter.notifyItemChanged(integer);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

```
private MutableLiveData<Integer> _update = new MutableLiveData<>(-2);
public LiveData<Integer> update = _update;

public void updateLiveData(Integer b){
    try {
        _update.setValue(b);
    }
    finally {
        _update.setValue(-2);
    }
    }
```

}

You'll have to use ViewModel in this, as you cannot make changes to another views in Recycler View

Comment: your code is for a single row right .But i want to select player B as captain and in if i select player E as captain then player B should get un-selected same as for vice captain.Like single selection of radio button vertically and horizontally

Comment: You need to implement RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener in your ViewHolder rather than writing onClick logic in onBindViewHolder

Comment: Recycler view reuses the views.Your ViewHolder should contain the onClick logic for rows. If you put OnClick logic in onBindViewHolder, then your onClick method inside onBindViewHolder will be invoked, whenever you scroll the recycler view which in turn will set the old values to other views.

Comment: it sets all vice captain selected and if captain selected vice captain is un selected but if i select any other player as captain and again if i select another player as captain then previous one does not unselect

Comment: its giving 
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Have you added the ViewModel Dependency in app level build.gradle ? If not, then you need to add ViewModel dependency in your project

Comment: it works .Thank you .But how to add my modal class data like boolean?

Comment: Instead  of  using isCaptain or isViceCaptain, you could use a variable "rank" in model class for all players, which can be vice captain, captain or empty string

Answer (score 0):

try with this one, In this i have create a model with with selected and unselected boolean for list and type for single selected radio button in row, it works for both verticaly and horizontal view , only one radion button is selected at a time .

```
  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioCaptains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:checked="false"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="Captain"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioViceCaptains"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:checked="false"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/radioCaptains"
    android:text="Vice Captain" />
```

and my adapter class is

```
   class SampleAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleAdapter.Items> {
private List<DataModel> list;
private Context context;

public SampleAdapter(List<DataModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list=list;

    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public SampleAdapter.Items onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_text, parent, false);
    return new Items(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SampleAdapter.Items holder, int position) {
    holder.mEventName.setText(list.get(position).getLevel());

    if (list.get(position).getChecked() &&  list.get(position).getType()==1) {

        holder.mRadioViceCaptain.setChecked(false);
        holder.mRadioCaptain.setChecked(true);
    } else if(list.get(position).getChecked() &&  list.get(position).getType()==2) {

        holder.mRadioViceCaptain.setChecked(true);
        holder.mRadioCaptain.setChecked(false);
    }
    else{
        holder.mRadioCaptain.setChecked(false);
        holder.mRadioViceCaptain.setChecked(false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return list.size();
}

public class Items extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
   private TextView mEventName;
   private RadioButton mRadioCaptain;
   private RadioButton mRadioViceCaptain;
    public Items(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mEventName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        mRadioCaptain = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioCaptains);
        mRadioViceCaptain = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioViceCaptains);

        mRadioCaptain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mRadioViceCaptain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (compoundButton.isPressed()) {
         Log.e("position",getAdapterPosition()+"");
         Log.e("b",b +"");
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                list.get(i).setChecked(false);
                list.get(i).setType(0);
            }
            list.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(true);
            if (compoundButton == mRadioCaptain) {
                list.get(getAdapterPosition()).setType(1);
            }
            else if (compoundButton == mRadioViceCaptain) {
                list.get(getAdapterPosition()).setType(2);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
}
}
```

My Model class is

```
   class DataModel {
 Boolean checked;
 int type;
String level;

public DataModel(Boolean checked, String level,int type) {
    this.checked = checked;
    this.level = level;
    this.type = type;


}

public Boolean getChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(String level) {
    this.level = level;
}
  }
```

initial value of checked variable  is false and type is zero like    below

```
 DataModel data4=new DataModel(false,"Bombay",0);
    DataModel data5=new DataModel(false,"Delhi",0);
    mCityList.add(data);
    mCityList.add(data1);
```

this works fine for my side.

Comment: i tried these one it works for row selection not whole items

Comment: no its works for all item i have already checked with 5 radio button.

Comment: i think you have list of items and each items contains radion button

Comment: now i used radio group as u told .yes 11 players will have each radio group in adapter